# Android crashes when I want to send an e-mail in my app

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail

I have an Android app which sends an e-mail message. But when I want to send an e-mail, my program totally crashes and I get the error:

> Process: com.example.jonas.shoppinglist, PID: 16791
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler
>               at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setContent(MimeMessage.java:1508)
>               at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.setText(MimeBodyPart.java:1155)
>               at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setText(MimeMessage.java:1547)
>               at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setText(MimeMessage.java:1531)

Now I show the code of the e-mail sender, the problem line is message.setText("the actual text");

```
import android.util.Log;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.activation.*;

public class MailSender {

    private String body;

    public void send() {
        // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
        String to = "abcd@gmail.com";

        // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
        String from = "web@gmail.com";

        // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
        String host = "localhost";

        // Get system properties
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();

        // Setup mail server
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

        // Get the default Session object.
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

        try {
            // Create a default MimeMessage object.
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

            // Set From: header field of the header.
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

            // Set To: header field of the header.
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(to));

            // Set Subject: header field
            message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

            // Now set the actual message
            message.setText("This is actual message");

            // Send message
            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (AddressException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I already did some research and people say it's a gradle issue, but I think I have all needed dependencies.
This is my gradle depencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.3.0'
    compile 'javax.activation:activation:1.1'
    compile 'javax.mail:mail:1.5.0-b01'
    compile 'javax.activation:activation:1.1.1'
}
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: FYI, you have javax.activation in there twice; once should be enough.  And you're using an old version of JavaMail; the current version is 1.5.4.  But since Android is not really Java, you might need the kludged version in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Java library (javax.mail:mail:1.5.0-b01) that might not be suited for Android. There is an Android version of javamail:
https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/ you should try that out. Don't expect that every library that works on Java will work on Android.

Comment: And how do I import that one?